# Error Unchecked call to 'put(K, V)' as a member of raw type 'java.util.HashMap'

Tags: java, arrays, json, hashmap

I am getting the error:

```
Unchecked call to 'put(K, V)' as a member of raw type 'java.util.HashMap'
```

This is the line that shows the error:

```
JSONArray FieldValues = new JSONArray(new JSONObject(new HashMap().put(K, V)));
```

Am I doing anything wrong or is there something I should add? any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `HashMap<typeOfKey, typeOfValue>()`

Comment: An error ? The HashMap parameter of JSONObject constructor is also not typed so any type of key or value is valid. Strange

Comment: [`HashMap.put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V)) doesn't return what you think it does.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the types.

Something like

```
new HashMap<Type1,Type2>().put(K,V)
```

should work.

Comment: It should, but it doesn't for me.  I initialize the HashMap in another method, and the warning comes whenever I try to `put` in a 2nd method.

Comment: You need to post some code up. At a guess you may have incorrect type info. Way out in left field guess is that you may have some type erasure issue.

Answer (score 24):

**For anonymous use:**

```
new HashMap<Type1,Type2>().put(K,V);
```

**For initializing a variable:**

```
HashMap<Type1,Type2> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put(K,V);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not defined what type of data your HashMap will store. 
Example:

```
Map<String, Object> hospedajeUpload = new HashMap<>();
```

In this example I assign the type String and Object.